# Segmentation fault from command line arguments in c

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am trying to read in a file and create an adjacency list from that file but when I go to read the file in from command line I get a segmentation error
gcc n00889642.c
./a.out test.txt
Segmentation fault

why is this happening?

```
main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    int index;
    int i;
    char vertex1;
    char vertex2;
    FILE *f = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    while (fscanf(f, " %c %c", vertex1, vertex2) != EOF)
    {
        for(i = 0; i<26; i = i + 1)
        {
            if(i == vertexCount)
            {
                InsertVertex(vertex1);
                break;
            }
            if(strcmp(graph[i], vertex1) == 0)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        for(i=0; i<26; i = i + 1)
        {
            if(i == vertexCount)
                InsertVertex(vertex2);
            if(strcmp(graph[i], vertex2)== 0)
                break;
        }
    }
    fclose(f);
    i = 1;
    while(i < vertexCount)
    {
        insertEdge(graph[0].vertexKey, graph[i].vertexKey);
        i= i + 1;
    }
    f = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    while(fscanf(f, " %c %c", vertex1, vertex2) != EOF)
    {
        if(strcmp(graph[0], vertex1) != 0)
            insertEdge(vertex1, vertex2);
    }
    fclose(f);

    printGraph();
    return 0;
}
```

This is the main segment of my code

Comment: Debug it and find out. Obviously you haven't tried - you aren't even checking the result of `fopen`

Comment: The first thing you should generally try when you get a segfault is to enable debugging symbols and run in a debugger. That will tell you which line of the program crashed.  However, there will generally be a logic error before that line, causing a pointer to contain garbage. You want to prevent those, not cure them. Good habits to get into: check the bounds of your arrays before you write to them. Check for errors on your library calls. Use `assert()` and `static_assert()` to ensure your assumptions about the program state are true. Whenever you use a pointer, you should know why it’s right.

Comment: You should also turn up compiler warnings and pay attention to them. On GCC/Clang, that’s `-g -Wall -Wextra -pedantic`. Clang also allows `-Weverything`.

Answer (score 2):

Couple things:

argv[1] - if only passing in one argument, should be argv[0] (should validate argc).

```
fscanf(f, " %c %c", vertex1, vertex2)
```

scanf requires address of variables to hold values, so should be:

```
fscanf(f, " %c %c", &vertex1, &vertex2)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in your `fscanf` statement

```
while (fscanf(f, " %c %c", vertex1, vertex2) != EOF)
```

You should supply the *address* of the target variables. It's also better to check the *number of fields converted*.

```
while (fscanf(f, " %c %c", &vertex1, &vertex2) == 2)
```

Also

```
 if(strcmp(graph[i], vertex1) == 0)
```

pays no heed to compiler warnings and might well cause seg-fault. It's unclear from your incomplete code what data type `vertex1` and `vertex2` are really supposed to be

```
InsertVertex(vertex2);
```

How can a `char` be a vertex?

Comment: I changed both the fscanf but i'm still receiving the segmentation fault, im not well versed in C and I seem to get this error a lot if i ever have to use it. The program reads that there are two arguments (the program itself and the file i'm trying to read) but it seems to have problems reading it

Comment: The program fully compiles and all the data types for comparisons are correct, I think the problem may be in my fopen, but i dont know really how to check for that yet.

Comment: @frznbullet answer updated. I do not believe you have no compiler warnings. Are they enabled? "*all the data types for comparisons are correct*" - they are NOT. `strcmp` does not take any `char` argument.

Comment: You check for `fopen` error by reading the man page. Did you do that? `if (f == NULL)`

Comment: my fopen does open the file, I tried to have my program instead just print all of the objects in the file and get a segmentation fault in while (fscanf(f, "%c %c", &vertex1, &vertex2) == 2)

Comment: I just figured out that my seg vault was because i declared by variables char vertex1 and char vertex2, i needed to declare then char vertex1[0] and char vertex2[0] so that it would limit them to only holding one char, thank you for your help